# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Tags: xmlhttprequest, mozilla

When i run the application in mozilla browser i am getting  the following error 
  Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

in other browser it is working fine

and in Mozilla browser page also it is not getting refreshed properly

Answer (score -1):

This is a warning, not error. If would an error then your page couldn't working properly.

Comment: exactly after this warning error comes: NetworkError: A network error occurred.